# how to add extra information on the user into firebase projects

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am having difficulties storing extra info on top of user using firebase admin library on node.js.

For example I would like to store an id for each user, let say organizationId.

What I have tried:

```
// Add user to firebase Auth Service
            admin.auth().createUser({
                email: email,
                emailVerified: false,
                password: 'secret',
                organization: 99,
                disabled: false
            })
                .then(function (userRecord) {
                    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
                    console.log("Successfully created new user:", userRecord.uid);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log("Error creating new user:", error);
                });
        })
```

This is creating the user with no complaining but when I try to get organization when user is logged in, it shows undefined.

I also tried to store id in photoUrl, this is not possible.

Is there any way that I can add extra info for the user? or is it the only way I have to create a db and store the organization id for each user specifically?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to add "extra information" to a user when created by the `createUser()` method of the Admin SDK. The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth?refresh=1#createUser) explains that you need to pass a [`CreateRequest`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.CreateRequest?refresh=1) object which contains a specific number of fields.

If you want to add extra info, you will need, as you've mentioned to create an extra document in your database (for example in `users` collection in Firestore).

You could use the following code in a Cloud Function (i.e. using the Admin SDK):

```
  ...
  return admin
      .auth()
      .createUser({
        email: email,
        emailVerified: false,
        password: password,
        displayName: userName,
        disabled: false
      })
      .then(userRecord => {

        const userId = userRecord.uid;

        const userDocRef = admin
          .firestore()
          .collection('users')
          .doc(userId);

       return userDocRef.set(userDocRef, {
          userName: userName,
          firstName: firstName,
          lastName: lastName,
          organization: 99
        });
      })
      .then(....)
```

Note that `photoURL` is one possible field for a [`CreateRequest`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.CreateRequest?refresh=1) object. So you might use this field or create your own specific field in the user document.

---

**Update, based on your comments:**

I understand that you want to save the users' extra documents in the Firebase Realtime Database (and not in Firestore) and that you have problems with setting the correct value for the userUid. You should use the square brackets notation, as follows:

```
var update = {};
update[userUid] = { organization: 999 };
return usersRef.set(update);
```

Comment: thou I am having problem creating the user into db using the following code:  console.log("Successfully created new user:", userRecord.uid);
                    let userUid = userRecord.uid;
                    console.log("userUid: " + userUid);
                    usersRef.set({
                      userUid: {
                        organization: 999,
                      }
                    });

Comment: the info are added to the database but the id of user is shown as userUid and not the actual uuid

Comment: Do I understand corectly that you want to save the users extra documents in the Firebase Realtime Database (and not in Firestore)?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using **Custom Claims**. I use custom claims to assign users to access groups as suggested in the Docs.

Refrence: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

```
admin.auth().createUser({ email: email, emailVerified: false, password: 'secret', organization: 99, disabled: false })
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    let u = userRecord.toJSON();
    admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(u.uid, { 'custominfo': false, 'morecustom': true }).catch(function(error) { console.log("Error:", error); });
  }).catch(function(error) { console.log("Error:", error); });
```

After assigning custom claims, the claims stay with the userRecord, and can be retrieved.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.trim(), password).then(user => { 
  firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdTokenResult().then(async idTokenResult => { 
    console.log("claims",idTokenResult.claims); }); });
```